# JQuery scale-up and scale-down effect from css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div inside a table which is empty lets say `category-1`, but the javascript function appends image to that div, iterating through the array and one more div that shows the text content when the scaling is happened lets say `box-1`, initially `box-1` is hidden.

Here what I am trying to do is when the array reaches the last element the div which contains the images scales to the center(with close effect)and div1 hides,at the same time the `box-1` which is hidden will scale up(with open effect) after 3 seconds of delay time again I want to close the `box-1` and at same time open `category-1` with scale up style(open style).

But I am not able to get the effect.

html:

```
<table class="screen_display">
    <tr>
      <td>
         <div id="category-1"></div>
          <div class="box-1" id="flip-1">
            <div class="trend">Trending</div>
            <div class="trend">Footwear</div>
            <marquee scrollamount="38">
               <strong><h1>Reebok</h1></strong>
            </marquee>
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.opensesame {  
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*background: #FAC8B6;*/
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s;
        transform:scaleX(1);
        animation-name: open;
        animation-duration: 0.3s;    
    }

@keyframes open {
        25%  {transform:scaleX(0.25);}
        50%  {transform:scaleX(0.50);}
        75%  {transform:scaleX(0.75);}
        100% {transform:scaleX(1);}
    }

.closesesame {  
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*background: #FAC8B6;*/
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
        transform:scaleX(1);
        animation-name: close;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;    
    }

@keyframes close {
        0% {transform:scaleX(1);}
        25%  {transform:scaleX(0.75);}
        50%  {transform:scaleX(0.50);}
        75%  {transform:scaleX(0.25);}
        100% {transform:scaleX(0);}        
    }
```

JS:

```
function startSlidecat1(started) {
    /*$('.box-1').css({transform:'perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg)'});*/
    for (var i = 0; i < footwear.length; i++) {
       var image = footwear[i][0];
       imgslidercat1(image, i * 2100, i == footwear.length - 1);
    }
};

function imgslidercat1(image, timeout, last) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('flip-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('category-1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('category-1').innerHTML = "";
    var product = document.getElementById('category-1');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product.appendChild(elem);
    elem.src = image;
    if (last) {            
        flip1();
    }
  }, timeout);
}
startSlidecat1();

function flip1(){    
   $('#category-1').css('display', 'none');    
   $('.box-1').delay(100).css('display', 'block');
   //$('#category-1').delay(100).addClass("closeover"); 
   $('.box-1').addClass("opensesame");  
   setTimeout(closeIt, delay_time);        
}

function closeIt(){
    $('.box-1').addClass("closesesame");     
    setTimeout(startSlidecat1, 400);     
}
```

In simple words when the array element reaches last item, the category should scale down smoothly and hides, smoothly scales up box-1, after 3 seconds delay box-1 slowly scales down and hides, smoothly scales up box-1. how can I do this?

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: @K.C. updated fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/1p7m9tng/3/